# How can we run a trigger manually?

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I am using SQL Server 2008 R2.

I want to know is it possible to run a trigger when I update a column from `tablelA` from 0 to 1?

Thanks in advance

Comment: How do you mean, manually? You can write, say an update trigger, which fires, when some column is updated, but that's hardly "running a trigger manually".

Comment: yes right by manually means i when i update a column value from 0 to 1 the trigger gets fires.

Comment: If that's an `AFTER UPDATE` trigger on that table - then yes, it will fire any time you update anything on that table. That's what triggers are meant to do. But that's not "manually" running the trigger... the `UPDATE` operation will cause the trigger to fire.

Comment: can you please give me an example so that i can implement it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE SomeTable 
(
   ID      INT          PRIMARY KEY,
   Col1    INT          NOT NULL,
   Col2    VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TRIGGER TR_SomeTable ON SomeTable 
AFTER UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
    IF UPDATE(Col1) 
    BEGIN
       UPDATE SomeTable SET Col2 = 'Col1 Changed'
       WHERE ID IN 
       (
            SELECT ID FROM INSERTED i INNER JOIN DELETED d on i.ID = d.ID
            WHERE d.Col1 = 0 AND i.Col1 = 1
       )
    END
END
```

Comment: @RGI: How should that help? What if someone updates any column other than Col1, then your condition will still yield true.

Comment: i just wanted to run the trigger when i will update the Col1,
i have a situation where i wanted to run the trigger by updating the Col1 from 0 to 1.